# html element whose text can be dynamically changed also an onclick action to point to a function NOT button

Tags: html

currently I am using a button whose 'value' i am able to change so that text written over button changes but I see that text is centered inside button & not big enough . Can I get something like +,- we see in windows explorer which enables to fold & expand folder in tree view.
i do not want to use any external file (img etc.) as I am creating a single self-sufficient webpage.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code for displaying + sign

----Firstly put this code in the head of your html.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function function_Name()
     { 
        alert('hi');
      }
   </script>
```

Then call the above function from this link here below, onclick event here call the above declared function:

```
    <a href="javascript:void(0)"style="textdecoration:none"onclick="return  function_Name();">&#43;</a>
```

Comment: to Isac_Pro .Net Developer
Ok . I used that anchor tag . Please tell me how can I associate an onclick function to it & change '+' to '-' inside that function . Previously I have used button whose value attribute can be changed. What will be the case here ?

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" style="text-decoration:none" onclick="return function_Name();">&#43;</a>                    <script type="text/javascript"> function_Name(){ alert('hi');} </script>

Comment: to  Isac_Pro .Net Developer
inside 'function_Name' how can I change the + or  &#43; to - ?

Comment: I tried as you said
[code]
<html>
 <head> 
  <title>change on click</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function function_Name()
   { $(a).val('&#45;');
   }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)"style="textdecoration:none"onclick="return  function_Name();">&#43;</a>
 </body>
 </html>
[/code]
error console said 'reference error:$ is not defined line 6'

Comment: I understand javascript a little bit , nothing about jquery.
I tried [code] <html>
 <head> 
  <title>change on click</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   function function_Name()
   { var alink = document.getElementById("a1");
    alink.val="-";
    alert('hi');
   }
   </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <a id="a1" href="javascript:void(0)" style="textdecoration:none" onclick="return function_Name();">&#43;</a>
 </body>
 </html>[/code]
This gave no error but just an alert , no change in name of link.

Comment: inside function now  use this code: $(a).text('&#45;');   it will change the text inside anchor tag

Comment: Isac_Pro .Net Developer   . I tried your suggestion , still same error . You can clarify me further by giving example code .
anyway , i found javascript solution at http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/89853/changing-link-text#

Comment: [code]
 <html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function exp(obj) {
 if(obj.oldText){
 obj.innerHTML = obj.oldText;
 obj.oldText = null;
 } else {
 obj.oldText = obj.innerHTML;
 obj.innerHTML = 'This text has changed!';
 }
 }
 </script>
 <body>
 <a href="#" onclick="javascript:exp(this);">Click here 1!</a><br/>
 <a href="#" onclick="javascript:exp(this);">Click here 2!</a><br/>
 </body>
 </html>
[/code]

worked for me . Thank you ,  Isac_Pro .Net Developer.

Comment: @user1371666 , Oh ! Great , there is no need to thanks , we all are here to provide solutions.